# Notifications on Discussion Forum

Tags: alert, discussion-board, notifications

I am using SharePoint 2013 and the notifications for the discussion forum don't seem to be working properly.
I do get notified if I reply to myself but not if someone else does!

Is there not an automatic notification for someone else replying to your posts or your replies? I'm pretty sure this was the case in SP2010. I don't want to have to set up alerts EVERY time.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have approval in place?

Comment: could you solve your problem? I'm having the same question and would be interested in the answer

Comment: I faced a similar kind of issue.
but I just updated and all the issues disappeared .
hope I am helpful.
Regards.